# Long Text MouseOver accordion

Tags: accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Is it possible to create the mouseover behavior on accordion with the long text push to up? So the screen will show the bottom of text inside accordion.

As per I knew is it only applicable when OnClick behaviour.

Try to find on google, but all only showing with onclicks

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "with the long text push to up"?

Comment: I mean if the accordion hover and display the long contents, the browser will auto scroll to the bottom of the accordion contents

Comment: Ah. That probably isn't built in because it's a bad user experience. If your accordion section ends up being taller than the height of the page, the top of the content gets cut off. And where do people start reading?

Comment: Exactly, that's also I told to my client, but this is what they want. :(. The accordion contents will similar like the TOC (list of pages) so not the articles contents

Comment: Anyway, is it possible if the user clicked/hover to expanded accordion will collapse?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to imagine how that would work. You could have it so the accordion closes when the mouse exits the accordion area, but then you're definitely tossing the accessibility compliance of your site out the window.

Comment: Can you please share the live example? I tried several code to close when mouse exit but seem no luck. Yes you right, this is really unique request from my client. Never got this before

Comment: Attached to mouseleave event, set accordion active attribute to false. http://jsfiddle.net/pbcg2cfm/

Comment: Thanks for the update code, but I tried in mobile is should double clicked to expanded.

Comment: A mobile user isn't going to know to double tap. You should probably just do browser sniffing and only include the hoverintent stuff when you know you're on a desktop browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/84L5o6oL/

Man that demo is infuriating to use.

In any case I took the hoverintent demo from the jQuery UI site https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#hoverintent and attached to the accordionactivate event, which fires after the accordion section has opened.

```
$( "#accordion" ).bind( "accordionactivate", function() {
       $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $('#accordion .ui-accordion-content-active').offset().top + $('#accordion .ui-accordion-content-active').outerHeight(true) -$(window).height()
       }, 500);
});
```

Inside of this I animated the scroll top to go to the bottom of the content of the opened element.

Now my real suggestion would be to explain to your client how accordions are a terrible UI pattern in the first place and should never be used to display content. http://www.nngroup.com/articles/accordions-complex-content/

Comment: Wow, thanks in a bunch for the help, specially for the suggestion link. Thanks